# Flutter build with CI getting error Program type already present: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I got some Error when build the flutter in CI/CD, i use `alvrme/alpine-android:android-29` as builder. i have try to run it in locally with `flutter build apk --split-per-abi` its run well

Here is my `app/build.graddle`

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.cdl.surelintas"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            minifyEnabled true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here is my `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here is my error detail:

```
 R8: Program type already present: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture
 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
 * What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForRelease'.
 > com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
 * Try:
 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
 * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
 BUILD FAILED in 8m 9s
 Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          494.2s (!)
 [!] The shrinker may have failed to optimize the Java bytecode.
     To disable the shrinker, pass the `--no-shrink` flag to this command.
     To learn more, see: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code
 Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
 Changing current working directory to: /home/developer/mobile_app
 Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                          
 R8: Program type already present: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture
 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
 * What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForRelease'.
 > com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
 * Try:
 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
 * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
 BUILD FAILED in 7s
 Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                              8.0s
 [!] The shrinker may have failed to optimize the Java bytecode.
     To disable the shrinker, pass the `--no-shrink` flag to this command.
     To learn more, see: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code
 Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1
 make: *** [Makefile:17: build] Error 1
 ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

I have looked through multiple stackoverflow solutions, still not work form me. myabe you guys has the same problem or soulution for this issues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution, this issues come acros duplicate class from dependencys. i have try some solusution in Stackoverflow but dosen't work. I got the solution at forum just add dependency below to your `app/buil.gradle` will fix the problem:

```
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android'
```

Hope this can help anyone with the same issues